# Customizing Elements in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, element

I am using CakePHP 2.3.6. Right now, I am doing a project, where I have several plugins. Now, I want the `Elements(header, footer, sidebar)` will appear in the default layout according to different plugins. I am trying to explain it using an example :

In my `default layout`, I have this for the header :

```
<?php echo $this->element('header');?>
```

Now, I want to keep the same layout in the `"AdminPanel" plugin`, so I am not gonna have a different layout in that plugin. But, I want a different `header(say, admin-header.ctp)` to reaplace that common `header(header.ctp)`, in the same layout, when I call that plugin. Is that possible ? If yes, how ? Please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: Why dont you make a new layout and call new elements in it ?

Comment: Actually, I was just looking for an easier & faster way. I thought, that'd be better. Yes, I can do it the way you said, but then I have to create another default layout,...etc. By the way, I think I can use if-else to detect the user-type. Thanks for your concern. @MoyedAnsari

Answer (score 0):

In your AppController beforeFilter or beforeRender put put something like:

```
if (isset($this -> params['prefix']) && $this -> params['prefix'] == 'admin') {
 $this->set('layout_type', 'admin');
}else{
 $this->set('layout_type', 'public');
}
```

In your default.ctp layout

```
if('layout_type' == 'admin'){
echo $this->element('admin_header');
}else{
echo $this->element('header');
}
```